# How Rxjava handle scope?

Tags: rx-java2

I'm trying to learn retryWhen in Rxjava.

I followed this [issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/5772) to have a limit number of retry times.

```
Observable.create(emitter -> {
            Log.d("test", "emitter error");
            emitter.onError(new Throwable("test"));
        })
                .retryWhen(throwableObservable -> {
                    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
                    return throwableObservable
                            .takeWhile(e -> counter.getAndIncrement() < 3)
                            .flatMap(count -> {
                                Log.d("test", "get count " + (counter.get() - 1));
                                return Observable.just(count).delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                            });
                })
                .subscribe(s -> {});
```

Why counter can store state for next retry?
What is the scope of local variable in Rxjave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why counter can store state for next retry?

because the lambda parameter of `retryWhen` gets executed for each individual subscriber it receives, thus what is declared inside the lambda will be uniquely associated with a subscription. This ensures multiple realizations of the flow will run independently with its own local couter.

> What is the scope of local variable in Rxjave?

The encompassing { }, i.e., the lambda body and any inner lambda it contains.